How to color the region between two ecdf?
I have summarized into a dataframe the mean values and the standard error of some experiments, like in this simple example:
mean <- c(-0.3378003,  0.7254329,  0.6568026, -0.1529680,  0.2809831, 
          -0.5420649, 0.7665903, -0.1624082,  0.9636990,  0.5978777)
se <-  c(0.1,0.04,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.06,0.09,0.12,0.05,0.02)

df <- tibble(nodeId =1:10, mean_val = mean, up= mean+se, low = mean-se )

"mean" is the vector of the mean values observed, "se" is the standard error vector. In the dataframe, I summarized the mean values and the confidence inteval computed with the standard error.
With the code below I plot the ECDF of the mean values, of the upper interval and of the lowee interval:
df%>% pivot_longer(., cols = 2:4,names_to = "type_values", values_to = "values") %>% 
      ggplot(., aes(x = values, color = type_values)) + stat_ecdf(geom="step")

I obtain this plot:

Instead of these curves, I would like to plot the ECDF of the mean values and to shade the area between the lower and upper curves. What can I do?

Does geom_ribbon not give you what you want?  You'll probably need two calls, one for low to mean and one for mean to up.

At first I tried, but in practice I do not know how to do it, since I do not have two "functions" to call, but their ECDF. In fact giving: df%>% pivot_longer(., cols = 2:4,names_to = "type_values", values_to = "values")  %>% ggplot(., aes(x = values, color = type_values)) + stat_ecdf(geom="step") + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin="mean_val",ymax="low"),color="grey") I does not obtain what I want

Try this approach:
(Using a different toy data frame to generate more data and with an arbitrary range for the ribbon.)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 0, 3), rnorm(100, 0, 10)))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin = after_stat(ecdf) - 0.1, ymax = after_stat(ecdf) + 0.1),
    alpha = 0.2, stat = "ecdf"
  )


Created on 2024-04-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the comment! Running your code, I got this error: Error in after_stat(ecdf) - 0.1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Do you have the same problem with this simpler approach?
